# Jquery progress bar color change

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

This is my jquery progress bar i want to the change the color for the progress bar with class of `Acceptedbar` to green and class of `Declinedbar` to Red

```
  <head runat="server">
    <title>Idea Storm</title>
    <link href="css/CSS.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.12/jquery-ui.min.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="script/ui.progressbar.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    ​<style type="text/css">

.AcceptedBar > .ui-progressbar-value {
   background:green;
}

.DeclinedBar > .ui-progressbar-value {
   background: red;
}
</style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <%-- <link href="App_Themes/HRIS-Theme/jquery.ui.core.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="App_Themes/HRIS-Theme/jquery.ui.theme.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />--%>
</head>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () 
    {
           $('.Accepted').each(function()
            {            
                var valueFromHiddenField = $('input[type=hidden]', this).val();
             $('.Acceptedbar', this).progressbar({ value: valueFromHiddenField});
      });


    });
    $(function () 
    {
       $('.Declined').each(function() {
        // We assume that there is only 1 hidden field under 'pbcontainer'
        var valueFromHiddenField = $('input[type=hidden]', this).val();
       $('.Declinedbar', this).progressbar({ value: valueFromHiddenField });
        });
    });


</script>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use CSS to style your progress bars, [details on theming here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/progressbar/#theming) :

```
.AcceptedBar > .ui-progressbar-value {
   background: green;
}

.DeclinedBar > .ui-progressbar-value {
   background: red;
}
```

[Working example here](http://jsfiddle.net/dmK8B/1/)

You cannot use `background-color` as the themes set a `background-image` so you must use `background`

Comment: <link href="App_Themes/HRIS-Theme/jquery.ui.core.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="App_Themes/HRIS-Theme/jquery.ui.theme.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> here what i have to chnage

Comment: ya i have added it but no change

Comment: Updated my answer a little - working now - I have included a CSS theme in my JSfiddle

Comment: can tell the golal link to include the CSS

Comment: it is not coming i think i doing  i have some mistake in these two lines   <link href="App_Themes/HRIS-Theme/jquery.ui.core.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="App_Themes/HRIS-Theme/jquery.ui.theme.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

Comment: where should i include this css

Comment: @SanthoshKumar where ever you want- as its more specific (ie using your class) it will work .. see my example here -> http://jsfiddle.net/dmK8B/2/ i load the jquery css after my custom css and it still works fine

Comment: @SanthoshKumar Check firebug / other debugger to find out what rule is being applied - can you create a http://jsfiddle.net to show your problem ?

Answer (score 3):

use like this....

```
    $('.Acceptedbar').css('color','Green');
    $('.Declinedbar').css('color','Red');
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change the style (ie. colors) in the CSS files, not in JavaScript.

Comment: how to change in the Css files for both the progrees bar

Comment: @Santosh Kumar , What is the id or class of both the progress bars.Are they divs?

Comment: div with class eg:  <div class="Declinedbar">
                                </div>

Answer (score 0):

In CSS file you could write ,

```
.Acceptbar{color:Green;}
.Declinebar{color:Red;}
```