# How to change jQuery progress bar color?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

I am working on asp.net mvc, i have placed a progress bar using `jQuery`. By default it's color is grey but i want to change it's color.

Also i have read the similar article and tried to do the same as described in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9907384/6854117) , but still i was unsuccessful.

Bellow is my script for progress bar

```
  $("input[name='cmdName']").on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', function (event, state) {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            //alert("On");
            data = "On";
            $(function () {
                var progressbar = $("#progressbar"),
                progressLabel = $(".progress-label");

                progressbar.progressbar({
                    value: true,
                    change: function () {
                        $('.Acceptedbar').css('color', 'Green');
                        progressLabel.text(progressbar.progressbar("value") + "%");
                    },
                    complete: function () {
                        progressLabel.text("Complete!");
                    }
                });

                function progress() {
                    var val = progressbar.progressbar("value") || 0;

                    progressbar.progressbar("value", val + 2);

                    if (val < 99) {
                        setTimeout(progress, 80);
                    }
                }

                setTimeout(progress, 2000);
            });
          } else {
            //alert("Off");
            data = "Off";

            $(function () {
                var progressbar = $("#progressbar"),
                progressLabel = $(".progress-label");

                progressbar.progressbar({
                    value: true,
                    change: function () {
                        $('.Acceptedbar').css('color', 'Green');
                        progressLabel.text(progressbar.progressbar("value") + "%");
                    },
                    complete: function () {
                        progressLabel.text("Complete!");
                    }
                });

                function progress() {
                    var val = progressbar.progressbar("value") || 0;

                    progressbar.progressbar("value", val + 2);

                    if (val < 99) {
                        setTimeout(progress, 80);
                    }
                }

                setTimeout(progress, 2000);
            });
          }
          $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("MultiGraph")',
            data: { data: data, search: search },

          });
        });
```

**Updated Code :**

Bellow i have added the color in `css`

```
.AcceptedBar > .ui-progressbar-value {
   background: green;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I assume : using `css` :)

Comment: It would need to be `background-color` (and the styles are defined by the `.ui-widget-header` class)

Comment: Kindly see the updated code

Answer (score 0):

There are two classes that you need to apply css in order to work.
Try as below:

```
.AcceptedBar> .ui-progressbar {
    background: green;
  }

.AcceptedBar> .ui-progressbar-value {
    background: white;
  }
```